# Mongoose connection error when connecting to mLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to mLab using Mongoose from my system but it keeps failing with the following error

```
 name: 'MongoError',
 message: 'failed to connect to server [server address here] on first connect' }
```

This is my code :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var options = {
    server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } },
    replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }
};


mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@server.mlab.com:port/appname', options);

var conn = mongoose.connection

conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

var User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    admin: Boolean,
    location: String,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
}));


var new_user = new User({
    name: 'name',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
});



conn.once('open', function() {
    console.log('started')
    new_user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('User created!');
    });
});
```

Please let me know how I can successfully connect to mLab.

Comment: have  you tried connecting with mongo client? maybe it's a network problem?

Comment: When I try from mongo client , I get this `error 0061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: try creating a new user and a password just in case, and make sure that user does not have read only access and try again. Seems to be an auth issue with what you information you have given

Comment: there might be a something wrong with mLab! I have the same problem with a my old credentials!

Comment: @CodePhobia tried . Still the same error

Comment: @Mohsen89z maybe yes. I tried from another system. Could not connect from that too.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue just now. In My case, I was connected to my office network through VPN and it was getting blocked.

Solution:- I disconnected from VPN and ran the command to connect and was able to connect.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue connecting through MongoDB URI and contacted them. The problem was that I had included a special character (@) in my password and parser treated it as a delimiter, so password was parsed wrong. They suggested to not include any special characters in your password and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me the error was caused by a userid and password with the wrong separator

mongodb://myuseridmypassword@ds112345.mlab.com:12345/mydb [wrong]
mongodb://myuserid/mypassword@ds112345.mlab.com:12345/mydb [wrong] mongodb://myuserid:mypassword@ds112345.mlab.com:12345/mydb [right]

While the node application successfully connect to MongoDB, the incorrectly formatted URI caused the driver to skip authentication. When I subsequently tried to insert a record authentication failed