# Mongoerror: authentication failed (code 18) when connecting to mLab from node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I am getting an 'authentication failed' error (code 18) when I try to connect to my mLab database from my node app. **The credentials I use are correct**; I have verified this many times. I have even created a new database user, but that did not change anything.

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

mongoClient.connect('mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds159387.mlab.com:59387/day-planner', (err, database) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: probably something's wrong with mlab! cause ur the [second guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780131/mongoose-connection-error-when-connecting-to-mlab?noredirect=1#comment68783750_40780131) with this problem for like 2 hours!

 try connecting with mongo client!

Comment: Typically one of two in things are in play. 1) wrong database username and password or 2) driver & server version incompatibility - mLab runs MongoDB 3.0+ with SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication for all shared plans: http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#version-compatibility

Comment: seeing this now...

Comment: I haven't used MongoDB in a while, but I don't remember finding a solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue connecting through MongoDB URI and contacted them. The problem was that I had included a special character (@) in my password and parser treates it as a delimiter as you can see in the URI, so password was parsed wrong. They suggested to not include any special characters in your password and it worked out.